# Read and write from parent to multiple children with exec program

Tags: c, exec, pipe, fork, dup2

Im quite new to C and am unsure how to proceed.

With this code I was attempting to create multiple child processes that would send their stdout to their parents stdin and have their stdin available to be written to with fdprintf of the pointer location in an array.

The code seems to not work, when executed with a basic program that reads stdin and prints to its stdout (which should be piped back). (In a different section of the main code I fprintf to where the pipe starts and then read stdin waiting for what should be written back).

```
int plumber(int *pipes[], int numChildren, char* command[]) {
    int i;
    char id;
    int nullSpace = open("/dev/null", O_WRONLY);

    for(i = 0; i < numChildren; ++i) {
        id = 'A' + i;
        pipe(pipes[2 * i]);
        pipe(pipes[2 * i + 1]);
        switch(fork()) {
            case (-1):
                fprintf(stderr, "Unable to start subprocess\n");
                exit(4);
                break;
            case 0:
                //child
                //close child's write, dupe its stdin to read
                //close childs old read
                close(pipes[2 * i][1]);
                if(dup2(pipes[2 * i][0], 0) == -1) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to start subprocess\n");
                    exit(4);
                }
                close(pipes[2 * i][0]);
                //close child's read, dupe its stdout to write
                //close childs old write
                close(pipes[2 * i + 1][0]);
                if(dup2(pipes[2 * i + 1][1], 1) == -1) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to start subprocess\n");
                    exit(4);
                }
                close(pipes[2 * i + 1][1]);
                close(1);
                //child stderr to nullspace
                if(dup2(nullSpace, 2) == -1) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to start subprocess\n");
                    exit(4);
                }
                close(2);
                execlp(command[i], "childprocess", numChildren, id, NULL);
                break;
            default:
                //parent
                //close read pipe from writing pipe
                close(pipes[2 * i][0]);
                //close write pipes and dupe stdin to read
                //close parents old read
                close(pipes[2 * i + 1][1]);
                if(dup2(pipes[2 * i + 1][0], 0) == -1) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to start subprocess\n");
                    exit(4);
                }
                close(pipes[2 * i + 1][0]);
        }
    }
    close(nullSpace);
    return 0;
}
```

The command is just to run the child process which also takes the number of children and an id from A to D. *pipes[] is numChildren*2 by 2 (so going along its child 1 read pipe, child1 write pipe, child2 read, child2 write etc.
Please help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The parent can have only one `stdin`.  Each time the parent does:

```
dup2(pipes[2 * i + 1][0], 0)
```

it is closing its previous `stdin` and replacing it with the read end of the pipe.  That means that all of the children, except the last, will have a `stdout` with a closed read end, which should cause them to receive a `SIGPIPE` (or an `EPIPE` error if `SIGPIPE` is ignored) if they attempt to generate any output.  Also, the parent has now lost its original `stdin`, which may or may not be important.

You should also check the `execlp` didn't return an error.  If it does, you will get very weird behavior, since the failed child will begin to spawn all of the remaining children concurrently with the parent.

If you really want all of the children's output to appear on a single `stdin`, then they must all use the same pipe.  However, this will cause their output to become randomly intermixed, so it will be impossible for the parent to know who sent what.  It would be better if the parent just kept the read end of each pipe in its original descriptor instead of trying to `dup2` them to 0.  In that way, the parent would retain its original `stdin`, and it could use `select` (or `poll`, or ...) to determine when it is getting input, and from which child.

It is generally a bad idea to connect a child's `stdin` and `stdout` to the same process (the parent) since it can easily lead to deadlock.  The pipe can buffer only a limited amount of data, and will back pressure (i.e. block) the writer when full.  If both the parent and child write a large amount of data into their `stdout`s, they will both be back pressured, which will prevent them from reading their inputs and draining the pipes.  You must either make sure that the child consumes all of the parent's output before generating any output of its own, or find a way to guarantee that you can always read from `stdin` even if `stdout` is blocked.  The latter can be accomplished by having separate threads deal with `stdin` and `stdout`, or by enabling non-blocking I/O and using `select` etc to determine when the pipe can be written.

Comment: On that last one, using `select` to determine when the pipe can be read/written, I've done that with named pipes but never tried with `STDIN`/`STDOUT`. POSIX does requires you to have the pipe open with `O_RDWR` so is that even possible with input/output streams? In any case you can probably still use `O_NONBLOCK` and back off with a sleep...